# TableView looks strange in Simulator & on iPhone

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, storyboard

I'm working on a little private helper app on keeping track of refueling my car and stuff..

Everything just worked fine until I started the simulator...

Here's how the TableView looks in the StoryBoard:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/brs24.png

And here's how it looks on the iPhone or Simulator:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFNwU.png

I already tried fixed, freeform and inferred sizes for the ViewControllers-
no success..

How can this be?
What causes this?

Comment: post your code so we can get a better look at whats happening

Comment: There is no real code. I linked some tableview content (labels and text field) to the .h file.. That's it.

Comment: have you set the cell size for the cells?

Comment: In the implementation or in the Storyboard?

Answer (score 0):

Think there's a quite long story to get there but I would try to answer the very question you asked.

You have probably composed your storyboard table view scene with a 'Dynamic Prototypes' content and then all the cells we can see in the storyboard are just namely prototypes, which can be used in runtime programmatically.

In order to make a scene in a wysiwyg manner, you should choose 'Static Cells' option instead.

[image]

Comment: They are static cells :/

Comment: No way... Six cells in storyboard and five cells in runtime. If I was you, I'll try to start it over again from creating a fresh new project :/

Comment: Is Oc... a label? Label in blue color? But that does not seem to exist in your first screenshot.

Comment: Yea, it grabs the current date.. And the color is coded

Comment: Ok, thought you just made a plain scene in storyboard but you did some additional job programmatically. Have you implemented data source methods in the to do the additional configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer. I was using "Size Classes" on my very first Navigation Controller.

Don't ask me why all my other Tabled didn't get messed up, but this was the solution for me.

Thanks for Your help! :)